# VTTEST and MOZILAVT HTTP methods, what are these?

Tags: http, http-method

I got several alerts in the last two days bcs our service responded 5xx in a large percentage of the requests (tipically offhours when we have zero to low traffic anyway).

When I checked the application logs I found these two;

```
Illegal request, responding with status ‘501 Not Implemented’: Unsupported HTTP method: MOZILLAVT

Illegal request, responding with status ‘501 Not Implemented’: Unsupported HTTP method: VTTEST
```

Any idea what are these, and which tools produce them? Google not helped.

It is clear that our site is under some kind of vulnerability testing, as I see the nginx access logs, but these requests are not there, which is even stranger.

Comment: No one knows? :-o I am also seeing these today, along with "TRAK" requests. Google doesn't return anything useful.